# If I write an @synthesize statement, will I get ivar with same name as property and without the underscore?

Tags: objective-c

Just a per the question title, I am aware that if I were to leave out the @synthesize statement I would get an ivar back with the same name of the property and a preceding underscore. So does it follow that if I manually write the @synthesize in a statement I will instead get the ivar with the same name as the property, but without the underscore?

Secondly, as a related question, would you generally advise to have an underscore fronting your ivar.. how should I think about best practice here?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: You want the property and ivar names to be different. There is a really good reason why Apple changed the defaults so the ivar has the underscore. It's less important with ARC than it was with MRC but it still a good idea to have two different names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> if I manually write the @synthesize in a statement I will instead get the ivar with the same name as the property, but without the underscore

Yes, you will (although there is a fuller form of `@synthesize` that lets you *state* the name that you want).

> how should I think about best practice here

Underscore is best practice; that is why it is what you get automatically when you declare a property. That way, you prevent accidental overshadowing. If they both have the same name, for example `myVar`, then you can say `self.myVar` or `myVar` and they are completely different things, which is an invitation to trouble.

Comment: And for more about this topic, see my book! http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html#_property_accessor_synthesis

Comment: The last sentence is huge. It eliminated a whole set of common bugs (as well as many related questions here on SO).

Comment: "a whole set of common bugs (as well as many related questions here on SO)" So true. Even better, switch to Swift, which is designed from the bottom up to prevent this and many other common mistakes.

Comment: Awesome, thanks guys. Really see now what you mean, Matt, by "A property (see Chapter 5) is syntactic sugar for calling an accessor by using dot-notation".

Comment: Matt, where you say, "Synthesis means that any accessors you don’t provide will be provided for you", by 'synthesis' you mean manual synthesis - using directive - rather than autosynthesis right?

Comment: won't let me edit - sorry I meant to ask if that means any accessors you don't provide will be provided for you in both manual synthesis AND autosynthesis, but of course that is what you meant! thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, if you simply write `@synthesize myVar`, you will get an iVar set up as `myVar`.  If you want another name, you can go with `@synthesize myVar = _myVar`.  Keep in mind that since Xcode 4.4 auto-synthesize all properties defined in your public class interface, so if you get something like:

```
@interface TestViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic) BOOL someBoolean;
@end
```

You will automatically have access to an iVar `_someBoolean`.

A good practice is to use a combination of public interface properties (when you need subclass or callers to give values or objects to your class) and private interface properties for your own needs:

**Example:**

```
// TestViewController.h
@interface TestViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic) BOOL someBoolean;
@property (nonatomic) SomeClass *someClassObject;
@end

// TestViewController.m
@interface TestViewController()
@property (nonatomic) NSString someString;
@end

@implementation TestViewController
- (instancetype)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        // Properties access by iVars
        _someBoolean = YES;
        _someString = @"Test";

        // Properties access
        self.someBoolean = YES;
        self.someString = @"Test";

    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

The difference between accessing a property directly or by its iVar is that for the former, the setter of that property is executed (if you implemented one).

Comment: The auto-synthesis of a property's ivar has nothing to do with ARC. You get that default even in a project setup to use MRC.

Comment: @rmaddy my bad, I forgot it came with Xcode 4.4, not ARC ;)